# If an SKAction is removed, is the completion still run?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skaction, completionhandler

As in the title, if I remove an action using `sprite.removeAllActions()`, does the action's completion still get run?

Here is a basic code snippet to help show what I am asking:

```
import SpriteKit

/// The action to add
let action = SKAction.moveBy(x: 10, y: 20, duration: 1.0)

/// The sprite to apply the action to
let sprite = SKSpriteNode(color: .white, size: CGSize(width: 50, height: 50))

// Run the action
sprite.run(action) {
    // Completion
    print("Completion")
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just quickly tested it after not receiving an answer. I discovered that the completion does **NOT** run if the action has been removed.